# Objective-C simple math issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have tried a lot of different syntax on this one and have had the right answer only a few times and then that was not reproducible.

I am just amazed at how simple this issue is and I have not found the answer, believe me I really don't want to ask it but I am new to Xcode.

I captured the screen for those who have trouble believing it.  vdif should not be 0 by the time the code reaches the breakpoint at line 136 that I am on.

[image: vdif should not be 0!!!!!!!]

Comment: What does labs do? - also better to show the code as text and not a graphic so others can cipy and run it

Comment: It will be zero depending on what `labs(vdif)` returns. Show us the rest of the code.

Comment: What is vdif value at 131 line?

Comment: Sorry I don't want to post the project, just want to know what could possibly cause this very basic issue.  labs just does absolute value of the float does't it?

Comment: Looks like that is it, labs doesn't do what I expected, sorry.

Comment: Check `man labs` vs `man fabs`.

Comment: labs() gives you the absolute value of a long integer. Maybe you wanted to use fabsf()?

Comment: Sorry I should have caught that! VB6 has only one ABS for all types, but still no excuse.

Comment: It is unnecessary to initialize values like that.  Either do `CGFloat vol1;` followed by the assignment or `CGFloat vol1 = 0.5;`, without the following assignment.  (And if you broke line 135 into the separate statements you'd see that vdif1 is being set to zero there, due to the inappropriate use of labs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `labs` function returns a `long` integer absolute value. You don't want to use `labs`, but rather `fabsf`, which returns a `float`, or `fabs` which returns a `double`.

See the `fabsf(3)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/fabsf.3.html).

Comment: In some cases `CGFloat` will be a `double`, not a `float`. So you would want `fabs`, not `fabsf`.

Comment: I should clarify that those cases are when compiling for 64-bit.

Comment: Correct, for 64-bit, `fabs` would be more appropriate. I added that to my answer.

Comment: Again, sorry, I looked up and added the labs too quickly after I got frustrated with the very small errors I saw in the values I entered.  0.55 got set as 0.55000001 and 2 numbers I thought were equal did not make it through the if statement, is there another way to handle that?

Comment: @KiloOne For gory detail on `0.55` vs `0.55000001`, see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Bottom line, it's because of these floating point rounding issues that you'd check that `fabsf(vdif)` is less than some value rather than checking to see if `vol1` and `vol2` are equal. I presume that's why you created the `vdif` variable in the first place. Perhaps I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: Rob, great link, like I said I tried a lot of syntax's, but they were all with labs.  I will simply put the condition back to if (fabs(vol1-vol2)<0.001) but just wanted to know if that is the most eloquent want to handle this issue, regardless of how ugly my post was, thanks.

Comment: @KiloOne Depending upon the app, I'd generally use `float`/`double` and do the appropriate rounding and/or `fabs`, but sometimes [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdecimalnumber_class/reference/reference.html) is a graceful solution.

Comment: Thanks, but if a big goal is to convert my program for Android use later, wouldn't it be better to stay away from types that aren't in all C versions?

Comment: @KiloOne I only threw the `NSDecimalNumber` approach out there because you implied that you wanted something more elegant. So, go ahead and stay with the standard "is the difference between two doubles less than a certain threshold value" logic, use a nice macro or function if you need to do this frequently.

Comment: If you're building an app for both 64- and 32-bit and you want to avoid casting or checking architecture, I would recommend `ABS()`. Still don't know why some people don't like it, but it bypasses the question of whether `CGFloat` is currently a `float` or a `double` and so alleviates the need to figure out which version of `fabs` to use.

Answer (score 1):

You use `labs` for float value, but it gets `long int` and returns `long int`, so `labs(vdif)` will be always zero in your case.

Use `fabs` for float values